# threads programming exercise - reading and writing . Mutex not needed?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I am trying thread programming exercise (from [HERE](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~melhem/courses/xx45p/pthread.pdf)) with some tweaks. I want to try 2 (or more) threads which read from a string one word at a time and then write to a buffer. Finally main thread will print the buffer written by threads.

I was surprised that my code works even if I don't use mutex lock to protect the write buffer ? in its current state - is this correct way to do things ? it produces correct output though.

Specifically the while loop in 'Hello' function: would it have been more efficient if mutex was used ? how to write code in that case ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int threadCount = 3;
int finish = 0;
int turn = 0;
void *Hello(void *rank);

char *str = "This is a really long string.. such a long string this really is... !";
char buff[512];
int index = 0;
int main() {
    long thread;
    pthread_t *hThread;

    hThread = (pthread_t *)malloc(threadCount*sizeof(pthread_t));
    if(hThread == NULL) {
        printf("\nERROR: malloc failed");
    }

    for(thread = 0; thread < threadCount; thread++) {
        pthread_create(&hThread[thread], NULL, Hello, (void *)thread);
    } 

    printf("Hello from main thread !\n");

    for(thread = 0; thread < threadCount; thread++) {
        pthread_join(hThread[thread], NULL);
    }

    printf("All threads finished !\n");
    printf("%s\n", buff);
    free(hThread);

    return 0;
}

void printMsg(void) {
    if(finish)
        return;     

    while(*str != '\0' && *str != ' ') {        
        buff[index++] = *str;       
        printf("%c",*str++);                
    }
    printf("\n");
    if(*str == ' ') {
        buff[index++] = ' ';
        str++;
    }
    if(*str == '\0') {
        buff[index++] = '\0';
        finish = 1;
    }
    turn = (turn +1)%threadCount;
}

void *Hello(void *rank) {
    long id = (long)rank;   
    while(!finish) {
        if(turn == (int)id) {
            printf("%ld : ", id);
            printMsg();     
        }
    }   
    return NULL;
}
```

I can see output produced as:

```
0 : This
Hello from main thread !
1 : is
2 : a
0 : really
1 : long
2 : string..
0 : such
1 : a
2 : long
0 : string
1 : this
2 : really
0 : is...
1 : !
All threads finished !
This is a really long string.. such a long string this really is... !
```

Comment: Your code works because you're only allowing a single thread to access `printMsg` at a time.  It's very inefficient since you have two threads constantly checking a condition instead of sleeping (your code will max the CPU).  It would be more efficient to only have a single thread.

Comment: Would it be efficient if I add mutex check:

    while(!finish) {
           pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            if(turn == (int)id) {
                printf("%ld : ", id);
                printMsg();     
            }
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }

so it will block the thread on mutex when it is held by another thread ?

Comment: You would not be maxing the CPU any more but you will still only have one thread at a time performing any work, so having only one thread would still be slightly more efficient.  The way you have set up this task is not really a good candidate for threading